# Which weapon has the highest dps?

Tags: candy-box-2

I have a choice currently between the troll bludgeon (12-16 damage, slow) or my silver sword (7 damage, medium speed). Which has a higher average dps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the troll for benchmark, and with the pink glove

Blundgeon end battle down 100 hp

Polished Silver Swords end battle down 130 hp

So bludgeon more effective?

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in the title:  the [Giant Spoon of Doom](http://wiki.candybox2.net/doku.php?id=the_giant_spoon_of_doom) has the highest DPS.

Answer (score 0):

> There is also scythe with 21 damage and "incredibly fast" speed which appears in forge for 5mln candies.

Answer (score 0):

The Polished Silver Sword has a maximum delay of 4 and deals 7 damage, and the Troll Bludgeon has a maximum delay of 7 and deals an average of 14 damage. Thus you can expect higher average DPS from the bludgeon.