# How many hits per second do the weapon speeds indicate?

Tags: candy-box-2

I am trying to find which does more damage per second: The polished silver sword or the trolls bludgeon. The one thing I don't know the frequency of hits from the weapon speeds eg. fast, slow, very slow. so i want to know: How many hits per second does each weapon speed do?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this question and the resulting answers, it seems the Trolls Bludgeon has more DPS:
[Which weapon has the highest dps?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137036/which-weapon-has-the-highest-dps)